# GreenPlum SQL to HiveSQL migration of query statement

Tags: hive, hiveql, greenplum

We have to migrate the GreenPlum SQL to HIVESQL as below statement, kindly help us.

```
to_date(b.birthday,'yyyymmddhh24miss')
extract(year from age(iDATE, to_date(b.birthday,'yyyymmddhh24miss')))
```

Above the two statement needs to convert SQL to HIVE. please help me.

hive version : 3.1.X

Answer (score 0):

Equivalent of `to_date(b.birthday,'yyyymmddhh24miss')`
is

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(b.birthday,'yyyyMMddHHmmss'))
```

However, i do not understand this `extract(year from age(iDATE, to_date(b.birthday,'yyyymmddhh24miss')))`. Do you need difference of iDate and birthdate ?
If yes, you can use to get date difference in years.

```
datediff(iDate,from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(b.birthday,'yyyyMMddHHmmss')) )/365
```

Hive also has `extract (year from datetimestamp)` functions.

Comment: select extract(year from age('2021-04-21', to_date('2021-04-25','yyyymmddhh24miss'))) --- yes we are just passing idate as parameter

Comment: age will not support hiveSQL, instead of that, how we can use?

Comment: You can calculate age - this is the difference between dates in year (I think). So use `datediff` to find out difference of dates and then divide it by 365.25 to get the exact year difference(you can cast to INT if you want).

Answer (score 0):

One more method of extracting timestamp is using regexp_replace:

```
regexp_replace(b.birthday,'^(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})$','$1-$2-$3 $4:$5:$6')
```

And age in years is:

```
cast(datediff(current_date,
             regexp_replace(b.birthday,'^(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})$','$1-$2-$3 $4:$5:$6')
             )/365.25 as int)
```

Comment: hi, how do we convert lpad(extract('hour' from time_stamp),2,0) as event_hour --? time_stamp is column

Comment: @karthikelavan Please  create another question, do not ask new questions in comments. Also please do not forget to Accept/vote the answer if it worked